# Spring Boot properties to change the directory of frontend resources

Tags: spring-boot, frontend, application.properties

I am having a Spring Boot application and I would like to change the directory of my frontend. Instead of having the frontend resources inside the directory `resources/static`, I would like to move them to another directory out of the `resources`. What would be the property I need to change so that my application considers the new directory for rendering the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure additional resources mapping using [`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html):

```
@Component
public class ResourcesMvcAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   private final Path resourcePath = Paths.get( ... );

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
             .addResourceLocations(resourcePath.toUri().toString()); 
   }

}
```